# InDesign: Multi-column text frame

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, layout

I have a text frame as wide as the document. It's divided by 12 columns (settings of the frame itself).

**How can I set a line to a range of e.g. 10 columns?**

There are only the options 2/3/4.

[image: Column Options]

Comment: My guess is it's not typical to merge more than 4 columns without breaking the flow of text. Have you considered using a regular text box on top with text wrapping? I'm guessing you want to add an excerpt of some sort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use paragraph style. You can type any value you want in the span column options.

Comment: Or if you don't want to use a paragraph style, just use the more full-bodied “Span Columns” dialog box found under the paragraph dropdown menu on the right (or directly accessible by clicking Cmd + Alt + J, if memory serves).